# EnumsNET generic method to cast enum to list

Tags: c#, generics, enums, enumeration

Error: The type 'Type Name' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'Parameter Name' in the generic type or method 'Generic Identifier'

```
 public static List<GenericEnum> GetEnumSelection<T>()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(v =>
        {
            var item = new GenericEnum { Id = Convert.ToInt32(v), Text = **v.AsString<T>**(EnumFormat.Description) };
            return item;
        }).ToList();
    }
```

I am trying to write generic class that will map enum [Description] attribute to class GenericEnum. Problem is with Enums.Net .AsString<> method since it can't cast to T.

Any advice?

Comment: What is `AsString`? Why not just use `ToString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to constraint `T` in your function to `struct, Enum`:

```cs
 public static List<GenericEnum> GetEnumSelection<T>() where T : struct, Enum
```

Incidentally, if you are using Enum.NET, you probably should be using their `Enums.GetValues<T>` instead as the performance will be better.